# How to combined enum values for an attribute in XSD?

Tags: xml, enums, xsd

I want to create an attribute (`gravity_layout`) which takes different combined values (for example: `bottom|right`)
How can I make this attribute? 
I have written this:

```
   <xs:attribute name='layout_gravity'>
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:union memberTypes='xs:string'>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base='xs:NMTOKEN'>
            <xs:enumeration value='bottom' />
            <xs:enumeration value='center' />
            <xs:enumeration value='center_horizontal' />
            <xs:enumeration value='center_vertical' />
            <xs:enumeration value='clip_horizontal' />
            <xs:enumeration value='clip_vertical' />
            <xs:enumeration value='fill' />
            <xs:enumeration value='fill_horizontal' />
            <xs:enumeration value='fill_vertical' />
            <xs:enumeration value='left' />
            <xs:enumeration value='right' />
            <xs:enumeration value='top' />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>
```

I can just define one value for it, for example just `right` or `bottom`, but if I  write `right|bottom`, then I get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

1. use XSD v1.1 assertions (not available in XSD v1.0) 
   and try to figure out a clever XPath to
   validate your micro-language of legal values separated by `|`
   symbols,

   ***or***
2. fix your XML design to use separate `source` elements for
   `layout_gravity` instead of jamming multiple values into a single
   `@layout_gratity` attribute:

   ```
   <layout_gravity>
     <source>bottom</source>
     <source>right</source>
     <!-- ... -->
   </layout_gravity>
   ```

I'd recommend approach **#2** because

- XSD (v1.1 or v1.0) will be able to represent your constraints naturally, and
- programs using your XML will be able to leverage XML parsers rather
  than have to micro-parse compound values stuffed into a single
  attribute.